# Why MySQL is giving this error while creating trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created this trigger for automatically generating user codes like SDA0001, SDA0002...
I have just included the main statements between BEGIN and END. It is create **BEFORE INSERT** on table **agent_mst**

```
DECLARE max_id INT;

SET max_id=(SELECT MAX(agent_id_pk)+1 FROM `agent_mst`);
IF (max_id IS NULL) THEN
    SET max_id=1;
END IF;

SET 
NEW.date_added=NOW(), 
NEW.date_updated=NOW(),
NEW.agent_code = CONCAT('SDA', LPAD(max_id, 4,'0'));
```

The error it is giving is as below

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE max_id INT; SET max_id=(SELECT
>   MAX(agent_id_pk)+1 FROM `agent_mst`); ' at line 1

I am creating this Trigger using phpMyAdmin.

Any suggestion what is wrong going here? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON `agent_mst`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_id INT;

    SET max_id=(SELECT MAX(agent_id_pk)+1 FROM `agent_mst`);
    IF (max_id IS NULL) THEN
        SET max_id=1;
    END IF;

    SET NEW.date_added=NOW(),
        NEW.date_updated=NOW(),
        NEW.agent_code = CONCAT('SDA', LPAD(max_id, 4,'0'));

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: nopes. still the same error. I am creating trigger using phpMyAdmin. Does that cause any trouble ?

Comment: @aslamdoctor - Dunno. Tried the command line or the workbench.

Comment: yeah it worked from command line. Got to learn something new. whenever create trigger from phpmyadmin, always include BEGIN and END statements even though it includes these automatically.

Comment: @aslamdoctor - I prefer the work bench for fiddling about. I then put the SQL into a script and just use the command line to do the business. Even create a script to just create the database etc.

Answer (score 0):

In mySQL for all pl/sql functions we should set delimiter first. Becoz it will take all semicolans as line end.